# Is there a way to subset arrays with nonmatching indices in python?

Tags: python, r

I'm currently working on translating an R file into python for the sake of reproducibility. I'm stuck on a user-defined function titled get_density (see below). part of the user-defined function uses R's kernel density estimator function, which returns a list of 3 arrays. My problem is in the last line of the user-defined function. In that line, the last element of the kde2d list is subsetted from the list, and that element is then subsetted by a separate matrix. When I try the same thing in python I receive the error "index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100."

I'm currently translating from rStudio in Spyder. I've recreated the kde2d and get_density function, except for the last line, but when I try to subset the resulting matrix 'z' in python, I continually get an error message.

Here is the original R code I am trying to translate:

```
get_density <- function(x, y, n = 100) {
  dens <- MASS::kde2d(x = x, y = y, n = n)
  ix <- findInterval(x, dens$x)
  iy <- findInterval(y, dens$y)
  ii <- cbind(ix, iy)
  return(dens$z[ii])
}
```

Here is my python translation:

```
def kde2d(vals1, vals2, N):
    x=np.linspace(np.min(vals1), np.max(vals1), N)
    y=np.linspace(np.min(vals2), np.max(vals2), N)
    X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
    positions = np.vstack([Y.ravel(), X.ravel()])

    values = np.vstack([vals1, vals2])
    kernel = sstat.gaussian_kde(values)
    Z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)

    return [x, y, Z]

def get_density(x, y, N):
    dens = kde2d(x, y, N)
    ix = np.searchsorted(dens[0], x)
    iy = np.searchsorted(dens[0], y)
    ii = np.vstack([ix, iy])
    ii = np.rot90(ii)
    ii = np.flip(ii)
    ii = np.flip(ii, axis=1)
    z = dens[2]
    return(z[ii])
```

it is the return(z[ii]) line that causes the error.

The result from the working R code is a numeric list of values, and that is what I want in python. However the only result I get in python is 
IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to R, Python, and most other programming languages, use *zero-based indexing*. So, an array/list with `n` elements starts with `x[0]` and ends with `x[n-1]`. In you case, `x[99]` is the last element of the list, and `x[100]` is out of range, so it produces an error.

Comment: How then would you fix my problem? I tried using N=99, and it gave me the same error except instead of 100, it said 99